# Web application still loading old webpages after updating the root files in IIS server

Tags: c#

I updated my models from the database and made changes to my c# web application but IIS server keeps loading my old webpages. When i run the application directly from the root folder the updated version shows correctly in the browser but, when i try to access it on the browser by typing localhost I get the old version that is not updated. I used the entity framework's database first facility to make my changes. I tried to:
1. Disable cache and kernel cache in IIS but i got no luck.
2. I tried to reset IIS using iisreset in cmd prompt but i got no luck.

I read somewhere where it says its probably using the old dll files but i have no idea how to go about this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-build your project if you are running directly from the solution directories or re-publish it if you have "uploaded" it from the solution directory to a web folder.

Comment: Cant vote it up. I have no voting points. I did try. Thanks anyway